# How to install "qemu-img" and use it to convert a "qcow2" image to a Virtual Box one?

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, convert, qemu

I have been asked to do some debugging work with `gnome-continuous`, but as this only comes in `qcow2` format for `qemu` and I do not want to install `qemu` at this time so this may be slightly problematic, though I have read here that one may be able to use `qemu-img` to convert a `qcow2` image to a Virtual Box compatible one. I have tried install `qemu-img` with:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-img
```

But it appears as though there isn't a package under that name currently in the repositories, so how do I install it and use it to convert the image? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The package you want is `qemu-utils`:

```
% apt-file search qemu-img
qemu-utils: /usr/bin/qemu-img
qemu-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/qemu-img.1.gz
```

So install `qemu-utils`:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install qemu-utils
```

To convert a QCOW2 image to a VirtualBox VDI image:

```bsh
qemu-img convert -O vdi test.qcow2 test.vdi
```

Or to convert to a VMDK image:

```bsh
qemu-img convert -O vmdk test.qcow2 test.vmdk
```

Or to convert to a VHD image:

```bsh
qemu-img convert -O vpc test.qcow2 test.vhd
```

Comment: Can one also convert the raw image to the `OVF` file type?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda First of all ... a good and interesting question, because most users are working with vbox and also correct and useful answer, so +1 for both ... a suggestion : why not install qemu and check it out ? The conversion (there always can go something wrong)  would be obsolete and KVM outperforms vbox, for your convenience there is a great GUI available ... sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-kvm virt-manager ... just give it a try, you will love it ! :)

Comment: qemu = no vt-x, so it seems to me vurtualbox is the only real option.